# При отключении инфоблока отображается "раздел не найден"

Tags: битрикс

CMS 1C bitrix.
В админке снимаю галочку "активный" с не нужного инфоблока. 
На странице собранной из разных инфоблоков отображается "раздел не найден", как убрать эту надпись?

Answer (score 0):

На нужной странице отключите подключение неактивного инфоблока. Или подключайте только активные инфоблоки.